# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs' when install webpack 4

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I updated webpack from version3 to 4 in my work project, and try to run server (npm run server), I have an error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
```

To install new version I use

```
yarn add webpack webpack-cli --dev
```

Here is my package.json scripts

```
"server": "webpack-dev-server  --config webpack.dev.js",
"build": "webpack  --config webpack.prod.js"
```

Comment: I have the same error when trying to migrate to webpack 4, did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, when I fix this error by install  webpack-dev-server@next, I get a new errors.

Comment: This madness with webpack is making me reconsider my career in web development.

Comment: I found decision - update all packages which have old webpack in dependencies, for me:  webpack-dev-server, extract-text-webpack-plugin,offline-plugin, webpack-manifest-plugin. And install webpack-cli.